# Sizer not behaving as planned…

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, centos7, wxpython

I am building a GUI with several different panels that I do not want to be in the same sizer: while they show related things, they should be separate. I have several panels, each with its own sizer being added to a top level sizer. So far, so good. However, I cannot figure out how to get the sizers to actually size the panels.

*I am interested in understanding what I am not missing, not a simple debug.*

Now, it appears that the behaviour can change depending on versions and OS, so here are mine:

- **CentOS 7**.
- **Python 3.6**.
- **wxPython 4.0.0b1**.
- To add to the complication this code must eventually work on **Windows 10** as well.

This is what I am currently getting:

[image: BAD!]

This is what I would like to happen:

[image: Good]

Although there are no border on the left and right, despite having added one. I suspect the sizer code is messing things up and thus ignoring borders.

The source code, such as it is:

```
import wx.lib.agw.floatspin as FS
import wx


class GUICalibration(wx.Frame):
    """A calibration GUI for raiju…"""

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        super(GUICalibration, self).__init__(parent, id, title)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('#5968c3')
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self._ui(panel), 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 3)
        sizer.SetSizeHints(panel)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def _ui(self, parent):
        panel = wx.Panel(parent)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(self._ui_prefix(panel), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        vbox.Add(self._ui_input(panel), wx.EXPAND)
        vbox.AddStretchSpacer()
        vbox.Add(self._ui_suffix(panel), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        vbox.SetSizeHints(parent)
        panel.SetSizer(vbox)
        return panel

    def _ui_prefix(self, parent):
        panel = wx.Panel(parent)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('steelblue')
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        _label = wx.StaticText(panel, label='')
        _label.SetLabelMarkup("<b><i><big>Calibration</big></i></b>")
        hbox.Add(_label, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.ALL)
        panel.SetSizer(hbox)
        return panel

    def _ui_input(self, parent):
        box = wx.StaticBox(parent, -1, "Calibration input")
        fgs = wx.FlexGridSizer(3, 3, 11, 11)
        flags = wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL

        _spin_count = wx.SpinCtrl(
            box, wx.ID_ANY, '0', min=0, max=1000, size=(128, -1))
        _spin_value = FS.FloatSpin(
            box,
            wx.ID_ANY,
            size=(128, -1),
            value=0.0,
            min_val=-40.0,
            max_val=100.0,  # FIXME
            increment=0.1)
        _spin_value.SetFormat("%f")
        _spin_value.SetDigits(1)
        _add = wx.Button(box, wx.ID_ANY, "Add calibration data")

        fgs.Add(wx.StaticText(box, label='Count'), 0, flags)
        fgs.Add(wx.StaticText(box, label='Value'), 0, flags)
        fgs.AddStretchSpacer()

        fgs.Add(_spin_count, 0, flags)
        fgs.Add(_spin_value, 0, flags)
        fgs.Add(_add, 0, flags)

        fgs.SetSizeHints(box)
        box.SetSizer(fgs)
        return box

    def _ui_suffix(self, parent):
        panel = wx.Panel(parent)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('steelblue')
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox.Add(
            wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL), flag=wx.RESERVE_SPACE_EVEN_IF_HIDDEN)
        _quit = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Quit")
        _quit.SetBackgroundColour('#5968c3')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnQuit, _quit)
        hbox.AddStretchSpacer()
        hbox.Add(_quit, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.SHAPED | wx.ALL, border=3)
        hbox.AddStretchSpacer()
        panel.SetSizer(hbox)
        return panel

    def OnQuit(self, e):
        self.Close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    """This is useful for testing the frame…"""
    app = wx.App()
    GUICalibration(None, -1, title='Calibration')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Worryingly, it appears that behaviour can differ between wxpython Classic and Phoenix and between Operating systems. So for clarity, you should state what you are using within your question. I have requested a wxpython-phoenix tag which, if it is approved, should help clear up some of the issues.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Urgh. That is less than good. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A passable solution reads thus:

```
class GUICalibration(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        self._logger = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)
        super(GUICalibration, self).__init__(parent, id, title)
        self._ui(self)
        self.Fit()
        self.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def _ui(self, parent):
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(1, 5, 5)
        sizer.Add(self._ui_frame(panel), 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 3)
        sizer.Add(self._ui_frame(panel), 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 3)
        sizer.Add(self._ui_frame(panel), 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 3)
        panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        return panel

    def _ui_frame(self, parent):
        sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL, parent, 'test',)
        sizer.Add(wx.Button(parent, -1, 'A very ' + 20 * 'long ' + 'text'), 0, 0, 0)
        sizer.Add(wx.Button(parent, -1, 'Small button'), 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 20)
        return sizer
```

The prefix and suffix code have been omitted to keep the code shorter but are included in the screen shot.

The problems with this solution are two folds: First, a re-sizing the window *does not* resize any of the sizers: they remain at the lowest possible size that fit. Second, I have lost the background colour of the top level panel. Why? I have no idea on either counts.

[image: passable solution]